# How to create a time series GIF web map?

Tags: web-mapping, timeslider

I found a web map on the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/03/08/climate/early-spring.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=photo-spot-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news) showing early spring conditions throughout the US. I've seen a much more complicated time-slider widget that can be used with ArcGIS Online web maps, however, I really like the simple lines in this map. What technology was used to create this GIF web map?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoServer has an [animation endpoint](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/animreflector.html) that can create animated gifs of this sort from time series data.

This [blog post](http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/animate-your-maps-with-geoserver-animator-tool/) shows some examples like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Don't know what the NYT uses, but Photoshop can create a GIF using its Animation toolbar from a stack of images in separate layers in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an open source option, [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) can do that. I did not try creating an animation using GIMP before, but this tutorial of [How To Create An Animated GIF From An Image Sequence Using GIMP](http://www.cubiclite.com/2015/06/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-an-image-sequence-using-gimp/) shows the steps of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use Camtasia to record the screen - in your case that would be a timeslider on auto-play - and then use option to export to GIF. Optionally you can speed up the video before exporting